# Get Wordpress widget CSS style to another text block?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, styles

I have one little CSS issue that dont know how to resolve myself (its little tricky). I want to get widget style (blue line bellow every widget that have it) to page text header so all elements will look the same. To show visually what i think:

[image]

and want to get the same style to "Doporučené Produkty" header title into same page.

[image]

I checked styles, and see that blue hover bellow every widget is related to this CSS:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus, h4.tt, h3.tt, .widget_gardengeneralposts h4, 
.list-custom-taxonomy-widget h4, .list-custom-taxonomy-widget li.current a, 
.widget_archive li.current a, .widget_categories li.current a, 
.widget_nav_menu li.current a, .widget_meta li.current a, .widget_pages 
li.current a, .widget_archive li:hover a, .widget_pages li:hover a, 
.widget_meta li:hover a, .widget_nav_menu li:hover a, .widget_categories 
 li:hover a, .list-custom-taxonomy-widget a:hover, .widget_categories li 
li:hover a, .widget_nav_menu li li:hover a, .widget_meta li li:hover a, 
.widget_pages li li:hover a, .widget_archive li li:hover a, .widget_pages li 
li:hover a, .widget_meta li li:hover a, .widget_nav_menu li li:hover a, 
.widget_nav_menu li:hover > a, .widget_categories li li:hover a, 
.widget_recent_comments li:hover, .widget_rss li:hover, .wtext a.active, 
.wtext a:hover, .dropcap-border, #bbpress-forums #bbp-user-wrapper h2.entry- 
 title {
  border-color: #070bf7;
  }
```

So someone to help me how to apply that style also to title text? [Link](https://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/) from URL with issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.vc_custom_heading {    
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0078;
    display: inline-block;
    border-color: #070bf7;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This should do it and margin to bottom is optional, but looks better on your site. Hope it works for you:)